# cypher filter relationship based on where not in

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('Entity1').
  has('name', within('BB', 'CC')).
  in('Entity2').
  where(
      not(
__.out('Entity3').
      __.out('Entity4').
      has('name', within('ABC', 'XYZ')).
      in('Entity5'))).
  in('Entity6')
```

Filter node where entity3 not connected with entity4 of name in ['ABC','XYZ']

Below cypher query has syntax error

```
MATCH(e1:Entity1{name:$name})<-[:Entity2]-()-[:Entity3]->(oEntity3)
where Not (oEntity3)-[:Entity4]->(oEntity4)
AND oEntity4 in ['ABC','XYZ']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCH 
    (e1:Entity1)<-[:Entity2]-(e2),
    (e2)-[:Entity3]->()-[:Entity4]->(e4),
    (e4)<-[:Entity5]-(e5)
WHERE 
    NOT e4.name in ["ABC","XYZ"] 
    AND e1.name in ["BB", "CC"] 
WITH e2 as entity2
MATCH (entity2)<-[:Entity6]-(entity6)
RETURN entity6
```

I think you missed filtering `e1.name` in your query,  posted originally in the question.

Comment: Yes .have updated the question, actually had missed another not in conidtion in the intial post 
Entity3 not (out of entity 4 and in  entity5)

Comment: got it. changed the query to match the updated gremlin query in the question.